# Using ASIHTTPRequest iPhone Classes

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i am trying to connect to w webpage to request Any Kind of data, right now.

i have not done much development in Objective c let alone webservice.

my code looks like this-

```
 [ASIHTTPRequest setShouldThrottleBandwidthForWWAN:YES];//will moniter the bandwidth and keep it at 14400,if using WWAN(Edge,3G,4G)
hello = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://allseeing-i.com"];//Request URL:
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:hello];//Requesting From URL
[ASIHTTPRequest throttleBandwidthForWWANUsingLimit:14400];//Bandwidth Monitor AKA Throttle.
[request startAsynchronous];//Send Request.
NSLog(@"%lu",[ASIHTTPRequest averageBandwidthUsedPerSecond]);//Logging bandwidth speed.
NSError *error = [request error];
if(!error){
    NSString *response = [request responseString];
}
testview.text = [request responseString];
```

im trying to display the String file to a text view, how would i go about writing that with these classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the code above, change `startAsynchronous` to `startSynchronous` and you'll see that the code following that actually works (or at least, is executed.)

Calling `startAsynchronous` means the request is going to be executed in the background, and then later will call your implementation of either `requestFinished:` or `requestFailed:` (I think those are the ASIHTTPRequestDelegate methods; I could be slightly off, but you get the idea... I hope.)

Comment: OH! See that cleared it up for me, thank you. also Asynchronous will run in the background....Synchronous will not change view until it gets the request. that's what i needed, thanks!

Comment: @MarkGranoff I think you mean "Calling startAsynchronous"

Comment: @Joe: Right! My brain and fingers got out of sync! Thanks. I've corrected the answer.